# vuejs ajax request using a v-model in a v-for

Tags: arrays, vue.js, v-model

I have a set of data (todos array) that displays in my model, and I am rendering this data in a list.

I am trying to implement a functionality on the list that whenever click on any item on the list, the `selected` variable's value should be updated with that item's`forumID`, and whenever a different item is clicked the selected variable should update accordingly.

I tried adding a `v-model`, but that breaks. So need some direction on how can I achieve this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  myId:"",
  selected:"",
    todos: [{"ForumId":41830,"Name":"test","Description":{"Text":"","Html":""},"ShowDescriptionInTopics":false,"AllowAnonymous":false,"IsLocked":false,"IsHidden":false,"RequiresApproval":false,"MustPostToParticipate":false,"DisplayInCalendar":false,"DisplayPostDatesInCalendar":false,"StartDate":null,"EndDate":null,"PostStartDate":null,"PostEndDate":null,"StartDateAvailabilityType":null,"EndDateAvailabilityType":null},{"ForumId":41863,"Name":"new forum","Description":{"Text":"","Html":""},"ShowDescriptionInTopics":false,"AllowAnonymous":false,"IsLocked":false,"IsHidden":false,"RequiresApproval":false,"MustPostToParticipate":false,"DisplayInCalendar":false,"DisplayPostDatesInCalendar":false,"StartDate":null,"EndDate":null,"PostStartDate":null,"PostEndDate":null,"StartDateAvailabilityType":null,"EndDateAvailabilityType":null}]
  },
  methods: {
  
          
       myMethod1() {
                var vm = this;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://example.com/" + vm.myId +"/blogs/"+selected+"/topics/",

                    type: 'Get',
                    headers: {
                        accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);

                        vm.Topics=data


                    }
                })
            }
  

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>

    <li v-for="(item, index) in todos"><a href="" v-model="selected" @click="myMethod1()">{{item.Name}}</a>
     
    </li>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***We can use the `v-model` directive to create **two-way data bindings** on form input, textarea, select elements, and custom components.***
The following error in your code also proves the above definition.

```
<a v-model="selected">: v-model is not supported on this element type. 
If you are working with contenteditable, it's recommended to wrap a  
library dedicated to that purpose inside a custom component.
```

Now, as you said, *" item on the list when clicked, grabs the `forumID` found in the dataset and replaces the `selected` value with that `forumID` changing whenever a different item in the list is clicked"*

This simply stated that you only want to **update the `selected` variable with the currently clicked item's `forumID`** which directly means-
*no two-way-binding is required == no v-model is required.*
So, why not use only a click event to update the selected variable?

Below is the demo in which when you click on any list item, the `selected` variable will update with that item's `forumID`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      myId: "",
      selected: "",
      todos: [{
          ForumId: 41830,
          Name: "test",
          Description: {
            Text: "",
            Html: ""
          },
          ShowDescriptionInTopics: false,
          AllowAnonymous: false,
          IsLocked: false,
          IsHidden: false,
          RequiresApproval: false,
          MustPostToParticipate: false,
          DisplayInCalendar: false,
          DisplayPostDatesInCalendar: false,
          StartDate: null,
          EndDate: null,
          PostStartDate: null,
          PostEndDate: null,
          StartDateAvailabilityType: null,
          EndDateAvailabilityType: null,
        },
        {
          ForumId: 41863,
          Name: "new forum",
          Description: {
            Text: "",
            Html: ""
          },
          ShowDescriptionInTopics: false,
          AllowAnonymous: false,
          IsLocked: false,
          IsHidden: false,
          RequiresApproval: false,
          MustPostToParticipate: false,
          DisplayInCalendar: false,
          DisplayPostDatesInCalendar: false,
          StartDate: null,
          EndDate: null,
          PostStartDate: null,
          PostEndDate: null,
          StartDateAvailabilityType: null,
          EndDateAvailabilityType: null,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    myMethod1() {
      var vm = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://example.com/" + vm.myId + "/blogs/" + vm.selected + "/topics/",
        type: 'Get',
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          vm.Topics = data
        }
      })
    }

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">Click on any item</div>
  <li v-for="(item, index) in todos" :key="index">
    <a href="#" @click="selected = item.ForumId, myMethod1()">{{item.Name}}</a>
  </li>
  <div v-if="selected" style="margin-top:20px;">
    Updated selected variable - {{selected}}
  </div> 
</div>
```

**Try this also-**

I called two actions together on the anchor tag's click, First, update the `selected` variable, and second, call `myMethod1` function.
You can also call `myMethod1` and pass `forumId` to it and update the selected variable inside it-

```
<a href="#" @click="myMethod1(item.ForumId)">{{item.Name}}</a>
```

And

```
myMethod1(forum_id) {
 var vm = this;
 vm.selected = forum_id
 // YOUR REST CODE HERE
}
```